# Jmeter Non GUI mode Error file doesn't exist or cannot be opened

Tags: jmeter

the problem i encounter appears whenever i try to use a non GUI mode in Jmeter. As You can see on the screen, when i start the test the error says that the file cannot be opened. I couldn't find any solution to that.

[image]

Best regards

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text; post the text as just plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is incomplete, but looking at my crystal ball I can see that you provided incorrect path to the .jmx file you're trying to execute

[image]

So double check that:

1. The [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) you're about to run is there
2. The user which opens the terminal has [read permissions](https://www.uwec.edu/kb/article/drives-establishing-windows-file-and-folder-level-permissions/) to that file or folder where the file lives
3. In certain cases Java doesn't "like" spaces and national characters in file/folder paths so try copying the script somewhere to `c:\temp` and running it from there

More information: [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

Comment: Thank You very much Dmitri :) Indeed it appeared that i used my national character so the Jmeter had problem with. When i corrected  the file and path name it works just fine :)